# Segmentation fault in qt, when allocating memory

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

After running, my app crashes. In debug mode on line `mManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);` appears window, informing about segmentation fault:
[image: Segmentation fault window]

Also, in Application Output I've got many strings of:

> can't find linker symbol for virtual table for 'QNetworkAccessManager'
>   value   found 'QCoreApplication::qt_static_metacall(QObject*,
>   QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' instead

Giving my code below.

**myclass.h**

```
class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void parseJSON(QNetworkReply *response);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *mManager;
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
   ,mManager{nullptr}
{
    mManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(mManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(parseJSON(QNetworkReply*)));
    std::cout << "Getting object from server..." << std::endl;
    mManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://some.url.com/cpp.json")));
}

void MyClass::parseJSON(QNetworkReply* response)
{
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyClass proc;

    return a.exec();
}
```

**UPDATE(1):** this problems occurred after ~10th build, before it didn't occur.
**UPDATE(2):** after cleaning and rebuilding the project everything worked properly. I don't understand, what was the problem.

Comment: Did you build Qt yourself?

Comment: @jpo38, I downloaded installation file and it installed Qt.

Comment: So it looks like something might be wrong w.r.t. linking in your build scripts somewhere, or in your environment (library paths) at runtime.

If it happens again, then you may want to set the [LD_DEBUG](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html) environment variable on Linux or the [DYLD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) environment variables on Mac OS X to get you a bit more information on which paths shared libraries symbols are being searched for and how the symbols are resolved. (Which operating system are you on?)

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm less familiar with Windows, but the [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx) utilities are pretty good, and looking at Process Monitor may help get more information. I haven't used [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in ages, but it looks like that's recommended on SO for getting this sort of information as well.

Comment: @Rob, ok, thanks very much for information.